# How to set up Kate to use Nautilus as a file manager?

Tags: nautilus, kate

I use Gnome-based Ubuntu 10.10 and Kate text editor.

If I right-click on a folder in Kate's file system navigation panel and choose to open the folder in a file manager, Filelight (a disk space occupation diagramming tool) pops up (which is far from what was intended). Can I set up Kate to open Nautilus in such a case?

Answer (score 2):

How much of KDE do you have installed? If you have the systemsettings tool, you could use it to change the application associated to folder. My guess is that there is filelight there at the moment and you want nautilus instead. If you don't have systemsettings, you might try something along the lines

```
grep -ri filelight ~/.kde
```

to find where the setting to use filelight is stored and change it manually.